# How can I modify my graph so it displays the proper information for the axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have written a program to solve the Heat Equation (`u_t = k * u_xx`) numerically by method of Finite Differences.

For my problem, `u` is  function of `x` and `t`, where `0 < x < L` and `t > 0`. I have specified `L = 1` (the length of the rod) and the terminal time `T = 10` seconds for my problem, so I would like for the graph to be displayed on the domain `(x,t) \in {(0,1) x (0, 10)}`. However, my axes just don't make sense. It is plotting the x-axis from values of `0 - 40` and the t-axis is showing `-0.25 - 0.00`.

How can I edit my code so that when I plot `u` which depends on `x, t` the graph will display for values of `x` ranging from `0 - 1` and `t` ranging from `0 - 10` seconds??

Thanks in advance for any and all help. it is very greatly appreciated. Here is the code I am working with:

```
    ## This program is to implement a Finite Difference method approximation
## to solve the Heat Equation, u_t = k * u_xx,
## in 1D w/out sources & on a finite interval 0 < x < L. The PDE
## is subject to B.C: u(0,t) = u(L,t) = 0,
## and the I.C: u(x,0) = f(x).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters    
L = 1 # length of the rod
T = 10 # terminal time
N = 40 # spatial values
M = 1600 # time values/hops; (M ~ N^2)
s = 0.25 # s := k * ( (dt) / (dx)^2 )

# uniform mesh
x_init = 0
x_end = L
dx = float(x_end - x_init) / N

x = np.arange(x_init, x_end, dx)
x[0] = x_init

# time discretization
t_init = 0
t_end = T
dt = float(t_end - t_init) / M

t = np.arange(t_init, t_end, dt)
t[0] = t_init

# time-vector
for m in xrange(0, M):
    t[m] = m * dt

# spatial-vector
for j in xrange(0, N):
    x[j] = j * dx

# definition of the solution u(x,t) to u_t = k * u_xx
u = np.zeros((N, M+1)) # array to store values of the solution

# Finite Difference Scheme:

u[:,0] = x * (x - 1) #initial condition

for m in xrange(0, M):
    for j in xrange(1, N-1):
        if j == 1:
            u[j-1,m] = 0 # Boundary condition
        elif j == N-1:
            u[j+1,m] = 0 # Boundary Condition
        else:
            u[j,m+1] = u[j,m] + s * ( u[j+1,m] - 
            2 * u[j,m] + u[j-1,m] )

# for graph    
print u, x, t
plt.plot(u)
plt.title('Finite Difference Approx. to Heat Equation')
plt.xlabel('x-axis')
plt.ylabel('time (seconds)')
plt.axis()
plt.show()
```

It appears that whatever displays for the x-axis reflects the number of step sizes in space that I take (`N = 40`) for my code. I thought `np.arange(x_init, x_end, dx)` would return evenly spaced values within the interval `(x_init, x_end)` with step size `dx`? So what am I doing wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: You only seem to be plotting `u`, what variables are you trying to plot?

Comment: huh.. I changed my code to this: `plt.plot(x, u)` and it now is giving me the same graph and `x` ranges from `0.0 - 1.0`. However I am still getting the vertical axis ranging from `-0.25 - 0.00`

Comment: What range are you expecting for your x and y axis?

Comment: `0 < x < L = 1`, `0 < t < T = 10` is what I would like for them to display

Comment: Would it be better/make more sense to create a 3D graph with height `u` and horizontal plane `(x, t)`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues with your code as your u turns out to be 40x1601 and not 40x1600. However, I think the plot you may be after (after correcting u) is

```
corrected_u = u[:,:-1:]
plt.pcolor(t, x, corrected_u)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This did in fact help me, however, why can you plot with the command `plt.pcolor(t, x, corrected_u)` but not `plt.plot(t, x, corrected_u)`?

Comment: `pcolor` is a patch colored plot as you see. `plot` is for plotting curves with syntax of `plot(x, y)`

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you so much!